# If S and T are transformattion mappings, what is [ST]?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

S and T are transformation mappings, what does [ST] and [TS] mean?

Does it mean transform via S and then apply T to the result and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juxtaposition of linear transformations means composition. In details, $ST$ means $S \circ T$ and $TS$ means $T \circ S$ (whenever they are defined, surely). This notation is used thinking of the following: $$T: V_1 \to V_2 \qquad S:V_2 \to V_3 \qquad S\circ T: V_1 \to V_3$$
Let $B_1, B_2, B_3$ be basis for the respective spaces (in finite dimension). Then: $$[S \circ T]_{B_1, B_3} = [S]_{B_2, B_3}[T]_{B_1,B_2}$$
At the bottom of our hearts, we know the distinction, so, writing, we oftem "confuse" the matrix with the transformation, so $S \circ T$ becomes $ST$. Actually, the identity above is the motivation for the definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: So if T: V1 -> V2 and S: V2 -> V1 then what is ST?

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? Think a bit.

Comment: Yes I've read it a number of times. I'm thinking ST: V1 -> V1

Comment: Yes, the composition goes from $V_1$ to $V_1$. To understand that notation better, I think it is important to take a look at matrices of linear transformations.

Comment: Great, and for the format of `B1,B3`, can the B3 also be written above B1 or is it B3 above B1?

Comment: I guess it depends on what notation the book you are reading has adopted. I already saw $[T]_{B_1}^{B_2}$ instead of $[T]_{B_1,B_2}$, but you must check what the book uses. I prefer this last notation.